# Understanding n-ary Cartesian product, understanding formula

Tags: elementary-set-theory

While I understand the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) I'm having trouble reading its set definition.

[image]

What I'm having trouble with is the $x_i$ part and my misunderstanding is that there is the variable $i$ that I assumed could be only one value at a time:

- $X_i$ represents all the sets from $X_1$ to $X_n$,
- $x_i$ represents the elements of those sets,
- if $i = 1$ then $x_i$ is a member of $X_1$ and further more is the first element of $X_1$, when $i = 2$ $x_i$ is the second member of $X_2$.

I would have used two variables, one $i$ for $x_i$ and $j$ for the set.

This is not correct so I would like some help translating this. I know the cartesian product is all the $n$-tuple possibilities taking every elements of every sets but I can't translate the formula above to that definition.

This formula for two sets' cartesian product makes much more sense to me:

[image]

Comment: $x_i$ is an arbitrary member of the set $X_i$, notice that, for $n=2$ you would have $X_1 \times X_2 = \{(x_1,x_2) | x_1 \in X_1 \, \text{and} \, x_2 \in X_2\}$. The cartesian product represent the set of all ordered pairs you can make with $n$ sets.

Comment: I would have used two variable one i for xi and j for the set Xj. It is just weird that there can be two values at once for i in the same expression, ence my confusion. The definition you commented for X1 x X2 I understand.

Comment: It's not having two values at once, it just represent an element of the set, that's why it's arbitrary. If you decided to define an index for each of them you would have to take into consideration the cardinality of each different set which would most definitely obfuscate things.

Comment: Do you understand now, Ced? Or is there something that needs to be clarified?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes the comment above yours further confuses me. He says we would have to take into account the cardinality of the set. However looking at the original formula there could be 3 sets of 1 element. In which case xi where i is n = 3 would not be a member of the set. I assumed that case was resolved with the part of the formula that says "such as xi is a member of Xi". Therefor I don't see why the cardinality would have to be taken into account.

Comment: Furthermore I still don't see how we can get the 1st element of 2nd set when "xi is a member of Xi". Either the variable i is 1 or i is 2, in the first case it's the first element of the first set, and when i is 2 it's the second element of the second set. Either that or i is all the values between 1 and n at once, in which case the comment above would be wrong when saying "It's not having two values at once".

Comment: There is just something that I'm reading incorrectly and I'm trying to figure out what it is

Comment: I think that's in reference to your statement, "when $i=2$, $x_i$ is the second element of $X_2$." If your statement were correct, then $X_2$ would have to have at least two elements, $X_3$ would have to have at least three, and so on. That is, if your statement were correct, then cardinality would have to be taken into account. But (as I think you understand) cardinality doesn't have to be taken into account, so your statement about $x_2$ being the second element of $X_2$ must be incorrect.

Comment: @GerryMyerson could you tell me in plain english how you read that formula ? I think that would help me more because I can't seem to express my misunderstanding

Comment: "$x_i\in X_i$ for every $i$ in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$" just means $x_1$ is in $X_1$, and $x_2$ is in $X_2$, and ... and $x_n$ is in $X_n$. "second element of $X_2$" is meaningless; sets are *unordered* collections of elements, $\{a,b,c\}$ is the same set as $\{c,a,b\}$, there is no such thing as, say, the second element of $\{a,b,c\}$. $x_2$ is just *some* element of $X_2$.

Comment: Let's look at an example. Suppose $X_1=\{a,b\}$, $X_2=\{c,d\}$, and $X_3=\{e,f\}$. Then $X_1\times X_2\times X_3$ is $\{(a,c,e),(a,c,f),(a,d,e),(a,d,f),(b,c,e),(b,c,f),(b,d,e),(b,d,f)\}$. Does that help?

Comment: In words: $X_1\times X_2\times\cdots\times X_n$ is the set of all $n$-tuples with first component an element of $X_1$, second component an element of $X_2$, ..., $n$th component an element of $X_n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not really, I know that already, my problem is that I did not understand how the formula translates to what you wrote. However your previous comment, makes me realize that maybe I understood the right part of the expression correctly and it's actually the left part that went over my head. What is in the parenthesis (x1,...xn) is actually all the possible combinations right ? For some reason I was pluging xi in there.

Comment: Okay thank you, I think I get it, the x1 in the original expression represents any element of X1

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that $x_i$ is not the $i$th element of $X_i$, but an arbitrary member (any element of $X_i$). For example consider the 2 dimensional cartesian product ($i =2$):
$$   X_1 \times X_2  = \left \{ (x_1, x_2) \, \Big| \, x_1 \in X_1 \text{ and } x_2 \in X_2    \right \}$$
Which by replacing $X_1$ by $A$, $x_1$ by $a$, $X_2$ by $B$, and $x_2$ by $b$ is equivalent to the formula you provided:
$$ A \times B  = \left \{ (a, b) \, \Big| \, a \in A \text{ and } b \in B    \right \}$$